# Can I collect a new payment method without failed cards going through?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

So the steps to reactivating an unpaid subscription in stripe is to 1. Collect new payment information. 2. Turn automatic collection back on by setting auto advance to true on draft invoices. 3. Finalize and then pay the draft invoices (make sure to pay the most recent invoice before its due date to update the subscription’s status to active).

My question is can I confirm the payment method right away without a failure card going through so I know for sure that I can pay the invoices? Or do I have to use webhooks and such for failed payments on the invoices.

Any idea how this can be done in React? Any references?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a React issue. Stripe would verify funds and send an appropriate response with a token that shows success/failure. Do you have some sample code that you can provide to show what you've implemented so far?

Comment: I'm using Elements and `stripe.confirmCardSetup(client_secret,` but this doesn't really fail on failure cards. I want to collect new payment information and make sure I can pay the invoices then and there.

Comment: Well in general there's no way to "know" if a card will work for an actual charge, you can't verify something like this upfront. Even if you complete a SetupIntent for a card and attach it to a customer, the actual real charge later might decline. Any payment can decline at any time regardless of past payments. There's not really such a thing as a "failure card" — a card can work for some payments and then fail for others. So really you'd just handle the declines on the Invoice payments themselves.